# angular 6 material2 mat-table MatRipple error

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular6

I can run MatTable in angular6 with datasource. However when tried to add sort or pagination below error coming -

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all
>   parameters for MatRipple: ([object Object], [object Object], [object
>   Object], [object Object], ?). Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
>   MatRipple: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object
>   Object], ?).
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata
>   (compiler.js:15700)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata
>   (compiler.js:15535)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata
>   (compiler.js:15020)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata
>   (compiler.js:14874)
>       at compiler.js:34412
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at compiler.js:34411
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (compiler.js:34408)
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata
>   (compiler.js:15700)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata
>   (compiler.js:15535)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata
>   (compiler.js:15020)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata
>   (compiler.js:14874)
>       at compiler.js:34412
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at compiler.js:34411
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (compiler.js:34408)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
>       at zone.js:858
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3662)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)

Below is the example code of **component.hml**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

   <ng-container matColumnDef="companyCode">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Company Code </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.companyCode}} </td>
</ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="companyName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.companyName}} </td>
</ng-container>

 <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

</table>
```

Below is the example code of **component.ts**

```
import {MatDialog, MatPaginator,MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';



export class GroupComponent implements OnInit  {

 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;



  constructor(private groupService: GroupService){
      this.displayedColumns = ['companyCode', 'companyName'];         
    }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getGroups();
  }

  getGroups(): void {
    this.groupService.getAllGroups().subscribe((groups: any)=>{
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(groups.value.data.companyProfiel);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }
}
```

Below modules are imported in the code of **module.ts**

```
import {
  MatButtonModule, MatDialogModule, MatIconModule, MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule, MatToolbarModule,
} from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: Maybe try import the `MatRippleModule` as well

Answer (score 0):

I have seen somewhere like, mat-paginator tag is using after closing table tag
like:-

```
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Your error also says like, it is some syntax error.